# display .raw file image in browser

Tags: javascript, image, jpeg, rawimage

I have a image file in .raw format which is directly read from fingerprint scanner device. We have to display that in a browser using html and javascript. How can we convert the .raw image and display in the browser?

**Following is the manual steps I used to convert using online tools**

I am able to convert that hex content as .raw file using online converter http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_file.php?lang=en

and converted raw file can be converted again as jpeg file by https://www.iloveimg.com/convert-to-jpg/raw-to-jpg url

Sample file will look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnycl.jpg

I tried the following code to display hex content in the browser but didnt work.

```
function hexToBase64(str) {
    return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, str.replace(/\r|\n/g, "").replace(/([\da-fA-F]{2}) ?/g, "0x$1 ").replace(/ +$/, "").split(" ")));
}

var img = new Image();
img.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+hexToBase64(getBinary());
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

complete jsfiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/varghees/79NnG/1334/

Comment: You'll need a script able to parse your *.raw* file, but there are actually many different file formats with a *.raw* extension. But since you were able to read it from [this service](https://www.iloveimg.com/convert-to-jpg/raw-to-jpg) it must be a common one, so in a way, you are lucky. Now you'll still have to determine which one it is exactly to be able to find a possible parser, or even build your own.

Comment: yeah i understand this. but if any tools already available on command line or java or any other programming language, it will help me to make it work easier

Comment: But we don't do library recommendations in here, and once again, your first step is to determine exactly what format you have.

Comment: okay. mine is list of pixel value range from 0 to 255. I have total of  92160 pixels. That must be converted as common formatter images

Comment: So you already know it's 8bits per pixel. And no metadata in the file itself about the size of the image? You have to guess? Hard to believe... But could be, since your image seems to be a square. In that case this fiddle might be able to do what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/6oqbu0jr/ (if so let me know)

Comment: Ah I just saw your own fiddle... So what you have here is not the list of pixels of the 256*256 image you provided, and it is not even the list of pixels of a square image.

Comment: Looks like this is what i am looking for. I am testing with actual data. If you make your comment as an answer i will accept it so it can be useful to others also.

Comment: Ok so the size of this image is actually 256*360px, here you can get it: https://jsfiddle.net/6oqbu0jr/1/ But I still don't bite the fact your original .raw file doesn't include metadata, with at least the size of the image. And for the answer, I'll make one in next two or three hours, running out of time right now.

Comment: Thanks. That did the work expected. If you like respond as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, what you have provided in your fiddle is probably not a .raw file.

While there are tons of different file formats using this extension, I don't quite bite the fact there is no metadata at all, since this is required to at least know the image's size.

So I'm sorry for future readers, but this answer only shows how to convert raw 8bit values into an actual image...

So now, without image size, but if the image is squared, we can actually do it from the byteLength only, (both width and height will be the square-root of the byteLength).

The general steps are

- (convert your hex string to an actual Uint8Array)
- set all 4th values of an Uint8ClampedArray 4 times bigger than the first Uint8Array (this will set the Alpha channel of our soon to be RGBA image)
- pass this Uint8ClampedArray in the ImageData() constructor.
- put this ImageData on a canvas
- Tadaa!

So using a square full of random values (and thus avoid the hex to buffer conversion):

```js
const fake = new Uint8Array( 256*256 );
crypto.getRandomValues(fake); // get random values

processSquareBitmap(fake.buffer);

function processSquareBitmap(buffer) {
 const view = new Uint8Array(buffer);
  const out = new Uint8ClampedArray(buffer.byteLength * 4);
  const size = Math.sqrt(view.length);
  if(size % 1) {
   console.error('not a square');
    return;
  }
  // set alpha channel
  view.forEach((a,i)=>out[(i*4)+3] = a);
  const image = new ImageData(out, size, size)
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = canvas.height = size;
  canvas.getContext('2d').putImageData(image, 0,0);
  // if you want to save a png version
//  canvas.toBlob(b=> saveAs(b, 'bitmap.png'));
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
}
```

But for not squared images, you must have the actual width and height.
I was able to deduce the ones of OP's hex data, and thus could make [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nyoz33tz/) which will display their image.

Comment: how we can convert 16/24 bit values to image, given that we know the width, height and depth itself? I am struggling with this.